# Can't not create, delete my partition on ubuntu 18.04 tried chown and chmod but not work

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount

I can't create and write file to my partition.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
sudo chown -R /media/thanhnv63366/SSD
```

Neither does this:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /media/thanhnv63366/SSD
```

This is what system show me when I enter mount on terminal:

[image: mount command image]

This is what happens when I try to create a folder or copy a file to my partition:

[image: error image]

This is my partition's info:

[image: partition info]

Comment: What kind of device / partition is that?

Comment: I edited the post for adding more information about my partition. Thanks for asking hope you can help me :(((

Comment: This is an NTFS formatted partition. NTFS is the format of MS Windows. Have it checked under MS Windows first of all. That likely will already solve the issue.

Comment: Thank for you comment @vanadium. But what do you mean about checking under MS windows. After I read this comment, I change into windows and try to create some file then when I change into Ubuntu OS I can use the partition normaly. But sometimes It's not work.

Comment: Use the disk checking tools (one of the system tools) of Windows to check and repair the drive. ntfs is a proprietary format, so you need Windows to check that drive.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for your helping. It's work well now.

Comment: @vanadium Would you be willing to post that, or something like it, as an answer? The information that led to your good advice was from the question itself (and obtained from within Ubuntu, even), so I don't think this question should be closed as "a problem that can't be reproduced." It should just be answered.

Comment: @EliahKagan Feel free to answer. For sure many other questions can be found here which boil down to an ntfs partition that is not clean.

Comment: @vanadium Most or all of them could perhaps be closed as a duplicate of something. (Btw, I've posted a CW answer based directly on your comments, but this is not to discourage you or anyone else from posting a new answer or editing that answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) gave the solution in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192397/cant-not-create-delete-my-partition-on-ubuntu-18-04-tried-chown-and-chmod-but?noredirect=1#comment1997934_1192397) (which was confirmed [to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192397/cant-not-create-delete-my-partition-on-ubuntu-18-04-tried-chown-and-chmod-but?noredirect=1#comment2000503_1192397)).

Based on the information in the question, it was possible to discern that the partition was formatted NTFS:

> This is an NTFS formatted partition. NTFS is the format of MS Windows.
>   Have it checked under MS Windows first of all. That likely will
>   already solve the issue.

[**vanadium**](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) [Nov 29 at 7:45](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192397/cant-not-create-delete-my-partition-on-ubuntu-18-04-tried-chown-and-chmod-but/1194689#comment1995933_1192397)

More specifically:

> Use the disk checking tools (one of the system tools) of Windows to
>   check and repair the drive. ntfs is a proprietary format, so you need
>   Windows to check that drive.

– [**vanadium**](https://askubuntu.com/users/558158/vanadium) [Dec 3 at 8:33](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192397/cant-not-create-delete-my-partition-on-ubuntu-18-04-tried-chown-and-chmod-but?noredirect=1#comment1997934_1192397)